# why gunicorn saying FATAL Exited too quickly (process log may have details)?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, gunicorn, supervisord

this is my gunicorn.conf file

```
[program:gunicorn]
directory=/home/ubuntu/js/
command=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/js/app.sock 
main_jntu.wsgi:application
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.out.log

[group:guni]
programs:gunicorn
```

after checking the status it shows

```
guni:gunicorn                    FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

help me this out.
and the log files are like this

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gunicorn'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn", line 7, in <module>
from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gunicorn'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn", line 7, in <module>
from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gunicorn'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn", line 7, in <module>
from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gunicorn'
```

Comment: The error message indicates that the *"process log may have details"* but you haven't mentioned what those logs contain.

Comment: how to check what the logs contain

Comment: how to check the logfile and how see the log file that what it contains @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: I don't remember ever using gunicorn, but based on the configuration you've shown, I would assume that `sudo cat /var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.err.log` and `sudo cat /var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.out.log` would be the way to see the log files.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the logs that i have found are     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gunicorn'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn", line 7, in <module>
    from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gunicorn'

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot check this bro i have mentioned